# "Stretch With OverFlow" option overlaps another text field

Tags: jasper-reports

I have set the "Stretch With Overflow" option True to some text fields (Denomination, From, To, Stock, Amount). There is one text field which is placed below these text fields ($F{grandTotal}). The below situation occur when I generate the report.

Can anyone please suggest what should I do to avoid this circumstance?

[image]

And this is the scenario of my report design.

[image]

Comment: You should post your *jrxml* file. Where is your *$F{grandTotal}* (what band: Detail or Column Footer)?

Comment: It is in Detail Band @AlexK

Comment: Can you post the template?

Comment: You mean, the .jrxml file? @AlexK

Comment: Yes, the *jrxml* file

Comment: Hi Alex, I couldn't upload the total .jrxml text file here. So, here is the link...
https://hotfile.com/dl/255281734/120a661/Daily_Stock_Report_Details.jrxml.html
Can you please check the file from the link? I hope I am not asking for a lot :)

Comment: Hi Alex, can you please check now?

Comment: Why you did not use grouping? Can you post the values of fields for the first 3 rows?

Comment: Did you get the result (on the picture) with help of this template?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer to this problem. Here is what I've done-

1. Right click on report name and select `Add Report Group`
2. Select a group name and click next.
3. Check `Add Group Footer` option.
4. Then place the `$F{grandTotal}` in the group footer and Voala! it's done.

Here is what happens: The group is added with respect to the `detail` band. So, my `$F{grandTotal}` field is placed perfectly after the detail band column values are generated.

[image]

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Move grandTotal to summary or ColumnFooter Band. In this use case I would suggest using a variable that aggregates "total" field so You don't need grandTotal field, unless grandTotal aggregates values not shown on report...